# I'm having trouble installing missing gems in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, installation

I'm having problems starting my Rails web server. I try to enter "rails server" in the cmd prompt but I get the following error:

```
C:\Ruby193\demo>rails server
←[31mCould not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available
on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

but whenever I then do a bundle install to install the missing gem, I get this error:

```
C:\Ruby193\demo>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.2.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.3)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.3)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.3)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.3)
Using mime-types (1.18)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.3)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.3)
Using activeresource (3.2.3)
Using bundler (1.1.3)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
Using execjs (1.3.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Installing json (1.6.6) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extensio
.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6
6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/g
nerator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then tried to install json without any luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, you need to install the Development Kit to be able to build gems with native extensions.

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit